# How to break a loop after it yields a certain number?

Tags: python, list

So here is my code, I have created this program so that it will run in a loop until either DIGITS 1 and 4 occur in the output, which will then break, but I want to change it in a way so that instead of "break" after either digits 1 or 4 are detected, I want it to break only after the output yields 1 or 4, how can I do that?? Here is my code..

what should I do to make sure it stops when the output itself, not the DIGITS in the output, the output itself, yields either 1 or 4?

Comment: @robbinc91 [It always does](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number).

Comment: sorry I misunderstood at first sight.

Comment: Your ```while loop``` does not change a thing every iteration. ```number``` is never changed so the same output is given. If number is never changed then your code will run indefinitely.

Comment: @robbinc91 Hmm, their Wikipedia page doesn't seem to actually say that you always reach 1 or 4, but I happen to know it's true :-)

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode yes. At first sight I did't see the '**2'. for that reason I deleted my first comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just loop over and over and check the entire `sum_of_digits`. Try this:

```
number = 145
sum_of_digits = 0
x = ''
while x not in ['1', '4']:
    for digit in str(number):
       sum_of_digits += (int(digit)**2)
    x = str(sum_of_digits)
    number = sum_of_digits
    sum_of_digits = 0
print(x)
```

my output: 4

This can be improved but I didn't want to change much more of your code

Comment: hey, Thank you very much for helping me. However, I just wanted to know that is there a way you can sort the variable 'number' to make the output display each value from largest to smallest?

Comment: You can remove the sum of digits thingy and everything because I understood your code already, but please show me whether is there a way you can sort the variable 'number' to make the output display each value from largest to smallest?

Comment: I'm not shure of understanding your last question, as the output will show only a digit. but for sorting the variable number you just need to convert the string into a list, and then apply the sort()function. If you want to reverse the string just use the flag reverse=True in the function -->> s = [i for i in str(number)]; s.sort(reverse=True);